# ElasticSearch: How to aggregate values from nested field with date range?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in ES that holds many kinds of statistics of the ads split by dates.
each doc contains the statistics of the days that the ad was active at.

I want to make an aggs that sums all statistics (clicks on ad for example) in range of dates group by country name.

**doc example:**

```
    "_index" : "ads_statistics",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "GKfumIMBQ_B0VJNY8PsU",
    "_score" : 9.962151,
    "_source" : {
      "statistics_by_date" : [
         {
          "date" : "2022-08-09 00:00:00",
          "countries" : [
            {
              "name" : "USA",
              "clicks" : 901
            },
            {
              "name" : "FR",
              "clicks" : 250
            },
            {...}
          ]
        }, {
          "date" : "2022-08-10 00:00:00",
          "countries" : [
            {
              "name" : "USA",
              "clicks" : 825
            },
            {
              "name" : "FR",
              "clicks" : 411
            },
            {...}
          ]
        }, {
          "date" : "2022-08-11 00:00:00",
          "countries" : [
            {
              "name" : "USA",
              "clicks" : 523
            },
            {
              "name" : "CZ",
              "clicks" : 23
            },
            {...}
          ]
        } }
```

I've write this code, but it returns 0s in aggs results:

**query:**

```
  "aggs": {
"statistics_by_country": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "statistics_by_date.countries"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "country_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "statistics_by_date.countries.name.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filter": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "statistics_by_date.date": {
                "gte": "2022-08-10",
                "lte": "2022-08-11"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_clicks": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "statistics_by_date.countries.clicks"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

**response:**

```
      "aggregations" : {
      "statistics_by_country" : {
      "doc_count" : 189,
      "country_terms" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 129,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "USA",
            "doc_count" : 3,
            "filter" : {
              "doc_count" : 0,
              "total_clicks" : {
                "value" : 0.0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "FR",
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "filter" : {
              "doc_count" : 0,
              "total_clicks" : {
                "value" : 0.0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "CZ",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "filter" : {
              "doc_count" : 0,
              "total_clicks" : {
                "value" : 0.0
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**notes:**

- *statistics_by_date.countries* and *statistics_by_date* from **nested** type in doc's mapping.
- *statistics_by_date.date* from type **date**

My ideal result with the range of 08-10 : 08-11 is:

- USA : 825 + 523 = 1348
- FR : 411
- CZ : 23

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Note that I edited the filter clause for the nested query.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "statistics_by_country": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "statistics_by_date.countries"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "country_terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "statistics_by_date.countries.name.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filter": {
              "filter": {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "statistics_by_date",
                  "query": {
                    "range": {
                      "statistics_by_date.date": {
                        "gte": "2022-08-10 00:00:00",
                        "lte": "2022-08-11 00:00:00"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "total_clicks": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "statistics_by_date.countries.clicks"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping simulate

```
PUT idx_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "statistics_by_date":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "countries": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST idx_test/_doc
{
  "statistics_by_date": [
    {
      "date": "2022-08-09 00:00:00",
      "countries": [
        {
          "name": "USA",
          "clicks": 901
        },
        {
          "name": "FR",
          "clicks": 250
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-08-10 00:00:00",
      "countries": [
        {
          "name": "USA",
          "clicks": 825
        },
        {
          "name": "FR",
          "clicks": 411
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-08-11 00:00:00",
      "countries": [
        {
          "name": "USA",
          "clicks": 523
        },
        {
          "name": "CZ",
          "clicks": 23
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it still returns 0s :|

Comment: I edited my answer. I put the mapping I used to simulate. Another change was in the date filter, I went back to using the statistics_by_date.date field